# using groups and accessor for serialization symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am writing on the Symphony site 2 using Twig, before I wrote application under the iPhone, when I wrote rest api I had a line in entity

```
/**
 * @var \Array
 * @Groups({"browser_details"})
 * @Accessor(getter="getArticleLikes")
 *
 */
private $likes;
```

such as where I could just get the likes, making no unnecessary actions by using the method $view->setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array($groupName)));

When I started writing on Twig site using the same entity in any way, I could not receive data from the groups and accessor controller, how use this annotation without FOSRestController?

Comment: Symfony is different. It has no Accesor annotation and only from version 2.7 a Groups annotation that is used for serializing objects and not to access properties. Reading your question it likes that you want to write an api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working for me.

Intead this:

```
$normalizer = new PropertyNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
```

Try this:

```
$normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [JMS serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) and [associated bundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) which will enable you to use these annotiations. Within your project if you follow the bundle installation instructions you should get what you need. I'd strongly suggest you read up the documentation to ensure that you understand what the serializer provides for you and how best to use it in your project.